# Eclipse ADT 17 causes memory leaks when editing layout UI?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

After upgrading to latest Eclipse ADT 17 , whenever I start editing layout in "Graphical Layout" mode it seems some major memory leak happens. Eclipse stats behaving strangely and need to restart eclipse.

I run eclipse Version: 3.7.2 on windows 7.

Did anyone else has observed similar issue ? Do you know any workaround ?

Thanks,

Tushar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26774&q=leak&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Comment: Comment 4 by mehmetal...@gmail.com  seems to make good workaround 

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26774#c4

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to ADT 20.0.3 should fix the problem (at least in my case it did) ;)

See http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview for details.